# jQueryMobile Div Slider

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, slider

I want to integrate a slider into my jQueryMobile project, but couldn't successfully integrate flexslider for my usage. The slider should not just slide images, but div containers, so that i can place buttons, form fields, images, etc. in it. It should look like this:

> [Mockup/Wireframe](http://s28.postimg.org/ribc4mva5/my_Image.png)

When the user clicks on one of the buttons on the left and the right side, the form slides and another form is shown. Or the user can slide like on native applications. Is there a plugin, or did someone build something similar to do so?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried with Flexslider? Please show some code. Flexslider should be fine for what you are after

Comment: The code is too much to paste it here. Are there any good examples for flex slider used in JQuery Mobile projects?

Comment: Here is a quick fiddle i made with flexslider: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/bPfdr/2/

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle. What about using flex slider not for the whole page, but for a list view within a page. I mean, you have several list views and one of them has this flex slider?